# How to use SearchAfter API correctly?

Tags: elasticsearch

I recently work with elasticsearch and I have such a question. I have a million documents in index and I wanna to get more than 10_000. For this I can use `scroll API` or `SearchAfter API`. I understood how does `scroll` api works but I have some problem with `SearchAfter`.

Here is my `SearchSourceBuilder` method:

```
public SearchRequest buildRequest(SearchDistanceParameters args) {
    final SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = prepareSearchSourceBuilder(args);
    final SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    return searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
}

private SearchSourceBuilder prepareSearchSourceBuilder(SearchDistanceParameters searchDistanceParameters) {
    final FieldSortBuilder fieldSortBuilder = new FieldSortBuilder("_id").order(SortOrder.ASC);
    final SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    final GeoDistanceQueryBuilder geoDistanceQueryBuilder = geoDistanceQuery(GeoLocationModelFieldName.LOCATION.name().toLowerCase());
    geoDistanceQueryBuilder.point(searchDistanceParameters.getLatitude(), searchDistanceParameters.getLongitude());
    geoDistanceQueryBuilder.distance(searchDistanceParameters.getDistance(), DistanceUnit.KILOMETERS);
    searchSourceBuilder.query(geoDistanceQueryBuilder);
    searchSourceBuilder.sort(fieldSortBuilder);
    searchSourceBuilder.searchAfter();
    return searchSourceBuilder;
}
```

Here I do sort before searchAfter() as mention in `SearchAfter` API doc.

Here I am sending my request to ElasticSearch:

```
public SearchResponse sendRequestToElastic(SearchDistanceParameters args) throws IOException {
    SearchRequest searchRequest = searchByDistanceRequestBuilder.buildRequest(args);
    return elasticDao.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT); // standard RestHighLevelClient.search method inside elasticDao.
}
```

And finally I am trying to get my objects from SearchResponse:

```
public List<GeoPointsFromElasticSearchResponse> searchByDistance(SearchDistanceParameters searchDistanceParameters) {
        final SearchResponse searchResponse = searchRepository.searchByDistance(searchDistanceParameters);
        return getGeoPointsFromElasticSearchResponses(searchResponse);
    }

private List<GeoPointsFromElasticSearchResponse> getGeoPointsFromElasticSearchResponses(SearchResponse searchResponse) {
        SearchHit[] hits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
        return Arrays.stream(hits)
                .map(hit -> {
                    final GeoPointsFromElasticSearchResponse geoPointsFromElasticSearchResponse = new GeoPointsFromElasticSearchResponse();
                    final Map<String, Object> sourceMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();
                    final Map map = (Map) sourceMap.get(GeoLocationModelFieldName.LOCATION.name().toLowerCase());
                    geoPointsFromElasticSearchResponse.setLatitude((Double) map.get("lat"));
                    geoPointsFromElasticSearchResponse.setLongitude((Double) map.get("lon"));
                    log.info("Sorted hits: {}", hit.getSortValues());
                    return geoPointsFromElasticSearchResponse;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

But I've got only 10_000 objects. It seems I am doing something wrong in last part. What am I doing wrong? How to use SearchAfter api in java correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Well the search API wont return all the documents in one request, the behaviour is similar as pagination.

You have to pass argument to search after:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/search-request-search-after.html

According to the constructor : searchSourceBuilder.searchAfter(new Object[]{sortAfterValue});

The value you want to set is the one returned by the first search request (hits => getAt(lastIndex) => getSortValues())